# How to use Sed to edit text in .srt file?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a problem with subtitle file(.srt). It doesn't work. And i want to add some parameter to many lines of text with Regex in Sed program.

changes from this pattern:

```
00:00:00 --> 00:00:06
```

to this:

```
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:06,000
```

",000" added after "hh:mm:ss"

How to write regex for this problem?

Comment: @Kane I asking about regex for change pattern "hh:mm:ss --> hh:mm:ss" to "hh:mm:ss,000 --> hh:mm:ss,000". I think regex is a kind of programming.

Comment: @terces907 apologies I misread your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/&,000/g' your_file.srt > new_file.srt
```

It will replace every occurrence of time in the format `XX:XX:XX` with `XX:XX:XX,000`. `&` is a special character which refers to the pattern found.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/(([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2})/\1,000/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/((^|\s)[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})(\s|$)/\1,000\4/g' file
```